# Cannot read properties of undefined react / js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props

I am learning React and passing props from parent to child etc and I have an issue with a component. In the React dev tools, the props are passed correctly through the chain but when I use the map() method on the array (hardcoded) it returns an error 'Cannot read properties of undefined. The props are correctly printed in the console, and thus I do not understand where this error is coming from.

This is what I did:

- I created a State in the App component
- The state is passed to SearchResults => TrackList
- The last step should be use the map method on the Tracklist component and pass each element of the prop to the Track component => This is where the error is

here the link to github here is the github link to my files, https://github.com/aspnet82/jamming

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your `PlayList` component. Your `TrackList` component expect `tracks` as a prop and you are not passing it in `PlayList` component.

**TrackList** Component

```
import React from "react";
import "./Tracklist.css";
import Track from '../Track/Track.js';

class TrackList extends React.Component {
  render() {    
    return (
      <div className="Tracklist">
        {
          this.props.tracks.map(track => {
            console.log(track)
            return <Track track={track} key={track.id}/>
          })
        }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default TrackList  ;
```

**PlayList** component

```
import React from "react";
import "./Playlist.css";
import Tracklist from '../TrackList/Tracklist.js';

class Playlist extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Playlist">
        <input value="New Playlist" />
        <Tracklist tracks={ARRAY_OF_TRACKS} /> // Pass Array of tracks here. 
        <button className="Playlist-save">SAVE TO SPOTIFY</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Playlist;
```

Comment: Not sure this is the correct answer. I am passing tha array to TrackList from SearchResults. If you look to the console, you have the state in the APp component and then props gos down APP => SearchResults => TrackList => Track

Comment: You are rendering the TrackList in PlayList. I can't find tracks prop there. I'll look into the project in detail. Give me a minute.

Comment: Yes, but if you look you'll see that TrackList is rendered in both and I am just working on the searchresults path, not the playlist. In any case thanks for taking the time! :)

Comment: I understand now what you meant ! Thanks you.

Comment: Cool! Glad this could help you.